# set null to None in Python, is it a good practice?

Tags: python, null

Very often when I deal with input/output that are generated from different languages, I often have to deal with the null values when I get those input/output into Python. As we all know `None` is the keyword for Python instead of `null`, so it often creates error when, say, the `null` value is in a list. Some libraries already deal with this situation, but some don't. I'm just wondering if it's a good practice to simply set

```
null = None
```

Honestly I haven't seen this done before, but I don't know if I'm just not paying attention. Is there any bad side effect for this? Is this even recommended?

EDIT: The current piece I'm working on does contain `eval`. I didn't it was such an evil thing lol. Someone wrote this a long time ago. I don't know how `eval` gave impression back then. nonetheless, I think it's a better idea to change the eval part.

Essentially the part that creates problem is when the code tries to eval a list that has `null` in it.

To be exact, the input here is a list of list that's wrapped in a string.

EDIT2: don't just downvote. I'm simply asking a question

Comment: I have no idea why that would be helpful.

Comment: I can only see this being of any use if you're using `eval`, *which you should not be doing.*

Comment: @MorganThrapp Because it would let something like `[1, null, 2]` work properly.

Comment: @MadPhysicist But what's the point? `[1, None, 2]` is the proper Python way of specifying that array. Either learn to code in proper Python or use C/C++/C#/Java; don't make it some mashup of un-idiomatic C-esque Python.

Comment: Are you trying to parse JSON with `eval` or something?

Comment: @madphysicist But why is that any better/easier/more readable that just using None directly?

Comment: @MorganThrapp Oh, it's not. This solution is crap.

Comment: to answer all your questions, yes, this piece of code contains `eval`. I guess I should work on that instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a good idea. It indicates some fuzziness in your program, a blurring of the line between code and input.

Any code you write should use `None`, not a variable set to `None`. Having a `null` constant wouldn't help because you could simply write `None`.

If you're getting input from the user or from another program, that input would be text. It'd be stored in a string variable as `"null"`. It wouldn't be a raw identifier `null`. It would be a very poor design if user input could somehow refer to variables in your source code. That would be leaking implementation details.

If you find yourself using `eval` or equivalent, go directly to jail, do not pass GO, do not collect $200.

Answer (score 6):

You're losing the advantages of `None`.  Try this:

```
None = "Hello"
```

It doesn't work (`SyntaxError`) because assignment to `None` is prohibited.  Creating an extra variable, `null`, introduces the *possibility* that `null is not None` at some future point in your program.

Just use `None`.  `None` is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm imagining you could receive input as a string `'null'`.  However, this would be a string and not a key word.  You'd be free to parse and deal with it as you saw fit.  The only way I can imagine using `null = None` would do anything is if you were trying to evaluate strings as python code like

```
null = None
`eval('null')`
```

I'd consider this **bad** and **sloppy** coding practice.

Answer (score -1):

I'm working with a response as a dictionary from a GET request from an API and received null and true as values of the dictionary.  I took your null = None and it fixed my issue

I also set true = True

return {"cancel_url": null, "initiator_id": null, "initiator_type": null, "is_visible_to_user": true}
NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).